# How to make a more complex global search in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird, search

In Thunderbird you can do a complex search with `strg+shift+f`, but just for each account. Besides, there is a global search field in the top bar where you can search for keywords in all accounts.

But I would like to use the complex search of `strg+shift+f` over all accounts. I would also like to create a saved search for that search.

The background is, that I usually tag all my emails and feeds that I need to work on with 1 (important). And I don't want to check each account for unsolved messages.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, its very easy, I found out that when you create a `search folder`, then there is a button `choose` where you can select even more accounts and folders to search in.

Its a bit illogical that its not already possible in the search before creating the search folder, but ok, it works for me.